# javascript access multidimensional object not working

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have an object:

```
var Obj = [{
    id: "",
    position: {
        cartesian: [],
        polar: [],
        bob: "INERTIAL"
    }
}];
```

When I go to set obt.id

```
Obj.id="sam/reconnaissance - "+samName;
```

It works fine.

However when I go to access  Obj.position.cartesian

```
(Obj.position.cartesian).push(fooBar[i][t][p]);
```

I get this error:

```
     (Obj.position.cartesian).push(fooBar[i][t][p]);
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cartesian' of undefined
```

Why? I have tried `Obj['position']['cartesian']` and still nothing

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obj is not an object, it is an Array so you have to access first element with index 0. Try it like

```
Obj[0]['position']['cartesian']
```

Comment: I will for sure! I got to wait 10 more mins stackoverflow says ;)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using an object, you are using an array.

An object looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    id: 0
};
```

What you have is an object within an array: (note `[`)

```
var obj = [{id: 0}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Obj is an array with single element as object, hence to access position you can use any of these syntax

```
    Obj[0]['position']['cartesian']
    Obj[0].position.cartesian
```

Again `cartesian` is an array hence to call push you can use

```
    Obj[0]['position']['cartesian'].push(foobar[i][t][p])
    Obj[0].position.cartesian.push(foobar[i][t][p])
```